# Dynamo DB .Net Object Persistence Model Not working When Hosted to AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using the .Net object persistence model to store item into Dynamo DB. It is working fine on my machine, but when I publish the project to AWS lambda service nothing is storing into database.

Please help.

Comment: P.S. While using Dynamo DB low level API I am able to store information into Dynamo DB using my AWS Lambda Asp .Net core 2.0 application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the issue by setting "IgnoreValue" to true in DynamoDBContextConfig. Remove the context.SaveAsync(model) from the code. below is the working code sample.

```
 [DynamoDBTable("User")]
public class UserModel
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey] 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

  }
```

After initializing above model below is code to insert item into DynamoDB.

```
public async Task InsertRecord(UserModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            using( var context = new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig { ConsistentRead = true, SkipVersionCheck = true,IgnoreNullValues=true }))
            {
                var dataContext = context.CreateBatchWrite<UserModel>();
                dataContext.AddPutItem(model);
                await  dataContext.ExecuteAsync();


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace.ToString());
        }

    }
```